# How to run crawler automatically?

Tags: python, django, cron, scrapy

I am using django and scrapy framework to complete a project. In my project, there are two crawlers. Now I want those crawlers to run once or twice a day automatically. So how can i achieve that? How is that achieved? Simple idea on using cron job is what I am looking for? So I am looking for some good and easy reference to start with.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Now a days we can accomplish using https://airflow.apache.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a cronjob would be the easiest way to go.

Simply add the following to your '`/etc/crontab`' (or use `crontab -e`):

```
0 0 * * * python /path/to/your/script.py
```

This will run every day at 00:00

Also here is some nice reference website: http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

edit: if you do not want the output be sent to your mail just use:

```
0 0 * * * python /path/to/your/script.py > /dev/null
```

or

```
0 0 * * * python /path/to/your/script.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The first will "destroy" the 'normal' output (but will log any errors), the second will "destroy" any output.

Comment: If your script runs from the commandline: yes it is that simple. For the seccond crawler just add another line like that, want to run it every 2 hours just use `0 */2 * * * python/path/to/script` If it doesn't work use the full path to python!

Comment: actually if i have to "scrapy crawl myspider"

Comment: if you normaly execute "scrapy crawl myspider" just do `0 0 * * * scrapy crawl myspider` It could be that you need to include a fullpath like `/usr/bin/scrapy` but just test it first and then lookup the path!

Comment: n00b question: Do you think this could be done also with messages?

Comment: No problem! You can automate a lot of things with crons, just check out the link I put in my answer it will teach you the basics!

Comment: @ikaros45 What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I have seen people complaining that cronjobs should not be used for async tasks; for that it's better a message (it is a kind of a to-do for the programme). I have never worked with messages, but sounds "logic" that this crawling task could also be done with messages... once again, I'm just being curious from the ignorance.

Comment: Well, of you run 2 cronjobs that depend on each other (for example script 2 uses the data fetched by script 1) then i would not recommend to add 2 cron entries. In that case I would simply say just make a "sh" file and add 2 lines, line 1 to execute the first script and line 2 to execute the second. In that case you will be sure the second it not executed BEFORE the first even when somehow it takes a lot longer than expected to finish the first script.